# remove all the occurances of "Meredith" from a text file

Tags: java, command-line, io

My program should get the arguments from the command line.  For example If I invoke java Test1 Meredith, removes Meredith from myFile.txt and sends the updated info into a new text file called targetFile.txt. Ad I'm not sure if it does access myFile.txt. How does it access? I mean how does it know that I need to access myFile.txt from the code below? Is that args[0]?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 4) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Usage: java Test1 myFile.txt targetFile.txt aaa ccc");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Check if source file exists
        File sourceFile = new File(args[0]);
        if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Source file " + args[0] + " does not exist");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        // Check if target file exists
        File targetFile = new File(args[1]);
        if (targetFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Target file " + args[1] + " already exists");
            System.exit(3);
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try (
                // Create input and output files
                Scanner input = new Scanner(sourceFile);
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(targetFile);) {
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                String s1 = input.nextLine();
                String s2 = s1.replaceAll(args[2], args[3]);
                sb.append("\r\n" + s2);
            }
        }
        try (
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(sourceFile);) {
            output.printf("%s\r\n", sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `s1.replaceAll(args[2], "");` to simply remove 'Meredith'?

Comment: It looks like you're writing the results back to the `sourceFile` and not the `targetFile`...

Comment: Ok I'm not sure if it gets access to myFile.txt at all.How does it know that that's the file I need to access in the first place?

Comment: *"Usage: java Test1 myFile.txt targetFile.txt aaa ccc");* - see it says `myFile.txt`

Comment: you can use `s1.replaceAll("Meredith", "");`  I don't see how there would be any issue with that...

Comment: *"Ok I'm not sure if it gets access to myFile.txt at all.How does it know that that's the file I need to access in the first place?"* - Based on your "usage" pattern, `arg` `0` should be the `sourceFile`, as demonstrated with `File sourceFile = new File(args[0]);`, since you're doing a check to see it exists or not one can assume that by the time it reaches the read/write section, the program has access to the file

Comment: And it still doesn't work

Comment: What did Meredith do to you??

Comment: lol I really didn't mean to remove her. She is a good girl. I was just so mad ar args[2].So tried to replace it with something more beautiful. I hope all the Merediths never be removed from anywhere

Comment: ok one more question. I created my own target txt file since this code didn't create it for me automatically. And It remains empty. no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This...

```
try (
        // Create input and output files
        Scanner input = new Scanner(sourceFile);
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(targetFile);) {
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String s1 = input.nextLine();
        String s2 = s1.replaceAll(args[2], args[3]);
        sb.append("\r\n" + s2);
    }
}
try (
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(sourceFile);) {
    output.printf("%s\r\n", sb.toString());
}
```

Seems to read from the `sourceFile`, build a new `String` (via `StringBuilder`) and then writes that back to `sourceFile`...

I would suggest changing to something more like

```
    try (
            // Create input and output files
            Scanner input = new Scanner(sourceFile);
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(targetFile);) {
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String s1 = input.nextLine();
            String s2 = s1.replaceAll(args[2], args[3]);
            output.printf("%s%n", s2);
        }
    }
```

I'd also suggest replacing...

```
System.out.println(
        "Usage: java Test1 myFile.txt targetFile.txt aaa ccc");
```

with something more like...

```
System.out.println("Usage: Test1 {source file} {target file} {source text} {replacement text}");
System.out.println("Where:");
System.out.println("\tsource file - is the source file to be read from");
System.out.println("\ttarget file - is the target file that the results are to be written to");
System.out.println("\tsource text - is the text to be replaced");
System.out.println("\treplacement text - is the new text to take its place");
```

which would be far more meaningful to users who have no idea what the program was meant to do or how it should work

> But my target file is still empty.don't know y. So no change basically

The modified code works fine for me, I suggest you're looking at the wrong output file.  Try adding...

```
System.out.println("Reading from " + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("  Writing to " + targetFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

before (or after) the read/write loop, this will print out the absolute paths to the files, compare that with the location of the file(s) you are trying to use

Comment: and this can be called as `java Test1 myFile.txt targetFile.txt Merdith ""`

Comment: Thank you so much this looks awesome. But my target file is still empty.don't know y. So no change basically

Comment: @CrazyGal Apart from the fact you're looking at the wrong file, no, because it works fine for me

Comment: so you see the results inside your target file?

Comment: @CrazyGal Yep, I end up with two files, one is the source file and one is the target file, it process 8151 lines, replaced 400 occurences of my source text

Comment: very strange for mine..

Comment: Where can I put my code so you can see? Do you mind if you put your whole code here?

Comment: Only if you can

Comment: @CrazyGal All I did was take your code, update it with my suggestions and it worked